# HAProxy redirect all traffic except for one url to https

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to redirect all traffic except for one file to https

My current config:

```
  frontend public
     # HTTP
     bind :80

     redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc } !{ path_beg -i /dont-redirect-this.php }
```

It successfully redirects all traffic but also `/dont-redirect-this.php` which I dont want it to.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this

```
redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ url_reg \dont-redirect-this.php } !{ ssl_fc }
```

Comment: **to keep clean:**
'acl check url_reg -i endpoint-check
redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc } !check'